# Wwise android integration

Tags: java, android

Has anyone ever implemented W Wise audio engine on android, and if you have please point me in the right direction in terms of tutorials and literature to read up.

I have tried to find some samples but they all seem to be in C++, however I am looking for something written in android. If you have anything please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use a C++ integration of WWise and combine it with your java Android app via JNI. 
Here's google's [JNI tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html) and a 
[JNI tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/awesomeguy/wiki/JNITutorial).